# How can I to hide nav and footer for my login and signup page in Next js 13

Tags: reactjs, layout, next.js13

I have login and Register page but the nav and the footer appears on all page. I dont know how to make the nav and footer not to appear in the login and register page. In Next 12, i usually used the `getLayout` function but in next 13 there is no component props in the layout page. How can i go about it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In **nextjs13** you have a `layout.js` file you can use but as per your use case you want **different layout for login, register** and a **different one for other routes**.

**Steps to follow**

1. Create route groups for the routes with navbar

- To group the routes create a folder inside app/ as `(folderName)`. *You can name your folder anything but don't remove parenthesis*.
- Now create a **dashboard folder inside app/(folderName)** and inside that you can create page.jsx file
- To access this route you can visit **localhost:3000/dashboard** *folder name inside parenthesis will be ignored.*
- Create a **new layout.js** file inside app/(folderName)
- Inside the **new layout.js** you can **add navbar** which will be used by dashboard and all other routes inside the group.

For reference - https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-groups

2. For login and register

- You can use the app/layout.js for login and register as this layout.js is without navbar.

Note: In the above scenario for dashboard you will have content from the layout.js inside group but you will also have content from app/layout.js
If you don't want that then delete layout.js from app/ and create a route group for login and register and a layout.js inside that route group separately for login and register. **Check multiple root layout in above nextjs docs link**

Answer (score 0):

You must use a different layout to your login and register pages.

Here is the Docs https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#nesting-layouts

But in resume you only need to create your file in the same context folder:

```
app/
| layout.js
| login.js
| register.js
| dashboard/
| | layout.js
| | index.js
```

This way the pages login and register will use the same layout, and any other page inside dashboard/ have the same layout.

Answer (score 0):

this is how i disable nav and footer :

```js
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation"
import { disableNavWithFooter } from "@/utils/disableNavWithfooter"

const Footer = () => {
  const path = usePathname()
  return (
    <>
      {!disableNavWithFooter.includes(path) && (
        <footer className="h-full bg-foreground text-background w-full mt-6 md:mt-10 xl:mt-16">
          {/* your code */}
        </footer>
      )}
    </>
  )
}

export default Footer
```

file **@utils/disableNavWithFooter.tsx** :

```js
export const disableNavWithFooter = [
  "/sign-in",
  "/register",
]
```